# Configure Postfix mail server to send emails to Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, certificate, smtp, postfix

I am running a Postfix mail server on an Apache web server on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Problem:**

I am able to send emails to my work email address, but I am unable to send them to my Gmail account. They do not even appear in the Spam folder.

I would like to send emails to my Gmail account from this Postfix mail server.

**Error in mail.log:**

[image: Error in mail.log]

**Setup:**

Postfix is configured to use SMTP authentication. I have used the commands below to configure it:

```
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_local_domain ='
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous'
sudo postconf -e 'broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination'
sudo postconf -e 'inet_interfaces = all'
sudo postconf -e 'smtp_tls_security_level = may'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_security_level = may'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_auth_only = no'
sudo postconf -e 'smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/mailserver.key'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/mailserver.crt'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_received_header = yes'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s'
sudo postconf -e 'tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom'
sudo postconf -e 'myhostname = example.com'
```

In the file `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf`
I have added the lines below:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

SASL installation and configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-2 sasl2-bin libsasl2-modules
```

Then edit /`etc/default/saslauthd`:

```
START=yes
PWDIR="/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
PARAMS="-m ${PWDIR}"
PIDFILE="${PWDIR}/saslauthd.pid"
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Update the `dpkg` state:

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --force --update --add root sasl 755 /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
```

Create a symlink for the config file:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/default/saslauthd /etc/saslauthd
```

**Certificate creation:**

I have tried with self signed certificates, created by OpenSSL:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mailserver.key -out mailserver.crt -nodes -days 365

sudo openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 365
```

I also have tried with my trusted SSL certificate that I also use for port 443 of my website. For that I had to concatenate the intermediate certificate with the domain certificate, but I had no `CAcert.pem` file after this process.

Do you see obvious flaws in that configuration? Please let me know if you need more details!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is the self signed certificate.  I successfully send mail to everywhere using a similar set up, but I use a Lets Encrypt certificate.  To send to Gmail you also need SPF and proper reverse DNS set up too.

I list mail.example.com as a MX for example.com and the SPF record for example.com allows all listed MXs.  `/etc/mailname` contains `mail.example.com`  Reverse DNS for the IP points to `mail.example.com`

```
root@ex1:~# postconf -n 
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/gnu_terry_pratchett
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_connect_macros = i j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.example.com, ex1, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = -
relayhost =
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_milters = unix:/spamass/spamass.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDB3-SHA, KRB5-DES, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_exchange_name = /var/run/prng_exch
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Comment: thank you, I will do the following and let you know if it worked: 1. Create Certificate using Lets Encrypt 2. use that certificate for TLS 3. set up SPF record and reverse DNS lookup